# Enable / disable on-screen keyboard using command line

Tags: gnome, touchscreen, dconf

Currently, I can navigate to "accessibility settings" and turn the on-screen keyboard on or off using the settings GUI.

How can I do this via the command line? so that it may be made a part of the script. A [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1187691/370026) has answers that rely on third-party code.

However, there must be a native way to toggle this setting? (since it's linux).

What is the native way? Other settings can be customized by dconf, can this be too?

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-keyboard-enabled true|false`

Comment: That solves it! Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the command line to enable or disable the Onscreen Keyboard is

Enabling:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-keyboard-enabled true
```

Disabling:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-keyboard-enabled false
```

Comment: This works. The UI option does not. Note that you can no longer uninstall `caribou` because it's either embedded or that's not what it's called anymore.

Comment: I stand corrected. It only works for the terminal. As soon as you start switching applications again, it turns itself back on.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Ubuntu 18.04